# File permissions with glass gdk

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I can create a JSON file in **DCIM directory** of Glass but the file is **not visible** when I access it on glass.

Here is the code:

```
File jsonFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "DCIM/test/file.json");
//file address    

String json = "{\"id\":1}";
//text to be written on the file

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(jsonFile);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(json);
bw.close();
fw.close();
//writing the file
```

I can only access the file in **DDMS** view in **Eclipse**.

I have added the following permission:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Tip. Use the new File(parent, child) constructor so you don't need to use + File.separator

Comment: Why would you create a JSON file in the Digital Camera IMages (DCIM) folder in the first place? Smells like you need to rethink your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can view it with DDMS that means the file was created. I think there is no problem with your app.

If you want to open the file, you can pull the file out from your Glass using adb:

```
adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/test/file.json
```

And view it with whatever application you want.

Also see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

> To copy a file or directory (and its sub-directories) from the
>   emulator or device, use

```
    adb pull <remote> <local>
```

Comment: The idea was that the user could load the file manually, using windows exporer or something more friendly. I performed some tests, with windows explorer the user can not see the file created by the application, but if user put the file, the application can load it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create a JSON file in the Digital Camera IMages (DCIM) folder in the first place? Smells like you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: you're right, I've since posted it as a comment on the Q.

Comment: Because in explorer i cant create new folders. The idea was that the user could load the file manually.

Comment: maybe Glass only allows reading of images from DCIM? So I wonder if simply changing the file extension to .jpg would work around your hurdle?